# "Constraint already exists" when using H2 with liquibase

Tags: java, spring, database, h2, liquibase

I'm using H2 as a test db, and Liquibase to initialize it. After the first few changelogs, I've got an error.

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'liquibase' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/liquibase/LiquibaseAutoConfiguration$LiquibaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelogs/changelog-create-professional-5.xml::5::admin:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Constraint "FK_USER" already exists; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.professional ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.user (id) [90045-200] [Failed SQL: (90045) ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.professional ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.user (id)]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1804) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:620) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:322) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1154) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583) ~[spring-context-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:740) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:415) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303) ~[spring-boot-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootContextLoader.loadContext(SpringBootContextLoader.java:136) ~[spring-boot-test-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContextInternal(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:99) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.test.context.cache.DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.loadContext(DefaultCacheAwareContextLoaderDelegate.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.test.context.support.DefaultTestContext.getApplicationContext(DefaultTestContext.java:124) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.outputConditionEvaluationReport(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:53) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:46) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-2.6.6.jar:2.6.6]
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:248) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit.jupiter.SpringExtension.postProcessTestInstance(SpringExtension.java:138) ~[spring-test-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$8(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.executeAndMaskThrowable(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:368) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$invokeTestInstancePostProcessors$9(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:363) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:195) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1655) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:484) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:474) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.forEachRemaining(StreamSpliterators.java:312) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:735) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.forEachRemaining(Streams.java:734) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:658) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.invokeTestInstancePostProcessors(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:362) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance$6(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:283) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.instantiateAndPostProcessTestInstance(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:282) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$4(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:272) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.Optional.orElseGet(Optional.java:369) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.ClassBasedTestDescriptor.lambda$testInstancesProvider$5(ClassBasedTestDescriptor.java:271) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.execution.TestInstancesProvider.getTestInstances(TestInstancesProvider.java:31) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.lambda$prepare$0(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:102) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:101) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.jupiter.engine.descriptor.TestMethodTestDescriptor.prepare(TestMethodTestDescriptor.java:66) ~[junit-jupiter-engine-5.8.2.jar:5.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$prepare$2(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.prepare(NodeTestTask.java:123) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:90) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541) ~[na:na]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.invokeAll(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:41) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$6(NodeTestTask.java:155) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$8(NodeTestTask.java:141) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.Node.around(Node.java:137) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.lambda$executeRecursively$9(NodeTestTask.java:139) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.ThrowableCollector.execute(ThrowableCollector.java:73) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.executeRecursively(NodeTestTask.java:138) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.NodeTestTask.execute(NodeTestTask.java:95) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.submit(SameThreadHierarchicalTestExecutorService.java:35) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestExecutor.execute(HierarchicalTestExecutor.java:57) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.engine.support.hierarchical.HierarchicalTestEngine.execute(HierarchicalTestEngine.java:54) ~[junit-platform-engine-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:107) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:88) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.lambda$execute$0(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:54) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.withInterceptedStreams(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:67) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.EngineExecutionOrchestrator.execute(EngineExecutionOrchestrator.java:52) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:114) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncher.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.DefaultLauncherSession$DelegatingLauncher.execute(DefaultLauncherSession.java:86) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at org.junit.platform.launcher.core.SessionPerRequestLauncher.execute(SessionPerRequestLauncher.java:53) ~[junit-platform-launcher-1.8.2.jar:1.8.2]
    at com.intellij.junit5.JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit5IdeaTestRunner.java:71) ~[junit5-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater$1.execute(IdeaTestRunner.java:38) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.TestsRepeater.repeat(TestsRepeater.java:11) ~[idea_rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:35) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:235) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
    at com.intellij.rt.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:54) ~[junit-rt.jar:na]
Caused by: liquibase.exception.LiquibaseException: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelogs/changelog-create-professional-5.xml::5::admin:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Constraint "FK_USER" already exists; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.professional ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.user (id) [90045-200] [Failed SQL: (90045) ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.professional ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.user (id)]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:124) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$null$0(Liquibase.java:265) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:177) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:176) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:155) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:239) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.lambda$update$1(Liquibase.java:264) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:177) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:176) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:155) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.runInScope(Liquibase.java:2404) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:211) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Liquibase.update(Liquibase.java:197) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.performUpdate(SpringLiquibase.java:314) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.integration.spring.SpringLiquibase.afterPropertiesSet(SpringLiquibase.java:269) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1863) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1800) ~[spring-beans-5.3.18.jar:5.3.18]
    ... 88 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.MigrationFailedException: Migration failed for change set db/changelogs/changelog-create-professional-5.xml::5::admin:
     Reason: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Constraint "FK_USER" already exists; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.professional ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.user (id) [90045-200] [Failed SQL: (90045) ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.professional ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.user (id)]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:695) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.visitor.UpdateVisitor.visit(UpdateVisitor.java:49) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.lambda$null$0(ChangeLogIterator.java:111) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:177) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:176) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:155) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.lambda$run$1(ChangeLogIterator.java:110) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:177) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:176) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:155) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:239) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator$2.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:94) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.lambda$child$0(Scope.java:177) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:186) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:176) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:155) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:239) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.Scope.child(Scope.java:243) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeLogIterator.run(ChangeLogIterator.java:66) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    ... 106 common frames omitted
Caused by: liquibase.exception.DatabaseException: Constraint "FK_USER" already exists; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.professional ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.user (id) [90045-200] [Failed SQL: (90045) ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.professional ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.user (id)]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:393) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:82) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor.execute(JdbcExecutor.java:150) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.execute(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1279) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.database.AbstractJdbcDatabase.executeStatements(AbstractJdbcDatabase.java:1261) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    at liquibase.changelog.ChangeSet.execute(ChangeSet.java:660) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    ... 126 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Constraint "FK_USER" already exists; SQL statement:
ALTER TABLE PUBLIC.professional ADD CONSTRAINT fk_user FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES PUBLIC.user (id) [90045-200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:576) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:429) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:205) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.get(DbException.java:181) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.tryUpdate(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:114) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.ddl.AlterTableAddConstraint.update(AlterTableAddConstraint.java:78) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.CommandContainer.update(CommandContainer.java:198) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.command.Command.executeUpdate(Command.java:251) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.executeInternal(JdbcStatement.java:228) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcStatement.execute(JdbcStatement.java:201) ~[h2-1.4.200.jar:1.4.200]
    at liquibase.executor.jvm.JdbcExecutor$ExecuteStatementCallback.doInStatement(JdbcExecutor.java:389) ~[liquibase-core-4.5.0.jar:na]
    ... 131 common frames omitted
```

This is the changeset that seems to be problematic:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
    <changeSet author="admin" id="5">
        <createTable tableName="professional">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="clinic_id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="user_id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="title" type="VARCHAR(5)"/>
            <column name="last_name" type="VARCHAR(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="first_name" type="VARCHAR(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="birth_date" type="DATE">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="email" type="VARCHAR(254)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
        </createTable>
        <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_user"
            baseTableName="professional" baseColumnNames="user_id"
            referencedTableName="user" referencedColumnNames="id" />
        <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_clinic"
            baseTableName="professional" baseColumnNames="clinic_id"
            referencedTableName="clinic" referencedColumnNames="id" />
        <rollback>
            <dropTable tableName="professional"/>
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Strange thing is, there are changesets, that have foreign key constraints in them, and they are initialized successfuly. For example:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<databaseChangeLog
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:ext="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext"
        xmlns="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-3.1.xsd
    http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog-ext http://www.liquibase.org/xml/ns/dbchangelog/dbchangelog-ext.xsd">
    <changeSet author="admin" id="4">
        <createTable tableName="patient">
            <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints primaryKey="true"/>
            </column>
            <column name="clinic_id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="user_id" type="BIGINT">
                <constraints nullable="false"/>
            </column>
            <column name="patient_id" type="VARCHAR(30)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="insurance_number" type="VARCHAR(30)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="title" type="VARCHAR(5)"/>
            <column name="last_name" type="VARCHAR(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="first_name" type="VARCHAR(50)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="birth_date" type="DATE">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="sex" type="VARCHAR(5)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="phone_number" type="VARCHAR(10)">
                <constraints nullable="false" />
            </column>
            <column name="email" type="VARCHAR(254)"/>
            <column name="comment" type="VARCHAR(255)"/>
        </createTable>
        <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_user"
            baseTableName="patient" baseColumnNames="user_id"
            referencedTableName="user" referencedColumnNames="id" />
        <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_clinic"
            baseTableName="patient" baseColumnNames="clinic_id"
            referencedTableName="clinic" referencedColumnNames="id" />
        <rollback>
            <dropTable tableName="patient"/>
        </rollback>
    </changeSet>
</databaseChangeLog>
```

Everything works in prod db (PostgreSQL). What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
            <addForeignKeyConstraint constraintName="fk_user"
            baseTableName="professional" baseColumnNames="user_id"
            referencedTableName="user" referencedColumnNames="id" />
```

The name you have used `constraintName="fk_user"` is very vague. It is extremely  posisble than another table has again reference to `User` table and uses a constraint with the same name `fk_user`. The constraint names must be unique so change this constraintName into something that will be unique for that schema.

You could use a specific name for the table `professional` for which the constraint exists. ex `fk_professional_user`.

The other foreign key constraints that you see in other changelogs working probably do not exist under other tables with the same names.

Comment: In fact the two changesets both contain a fk constraint with that exact name.

Comment: @JoachimSauer you are correct, have not seen that, but was extremely confident that this was the issue, because the table `User` (from experience based on the name it has) probably has been referenced in multiple other tables.